# Too many events stored in db On android monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building a CRUD android app using SQLite database, when run on emulator and no problem all goes OK but why on android monitor appear information as below continuously, but i do not do command on that application .. what is it a Error on my app? And if there is a bad impact if the application is already installed?

```
08-05 20:08:44.697 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:44.977 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:45.267 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:45.527 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:45.827 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:46.097 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:46.387 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
08-05 20:08:46.667 1051-1104/? W/MtaSDK: [StatStore(81): null:-1] - Too many events stored in db.
```

Comment: Could you post more of the stack trace and possibly part of the code you think is giving you that output ?